# How can I read windows product licence key from UEFI in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, command-line

There are some machines with windows 10 preinstalled where the product key is stored in the UEFI. **How can I retrieve this key?**

Comment: Not BIOS. UEFI is the name and although it serves the same purpose, **UEFI is not BIOS**.

Comment: Thx. Was in a hurry

Comment: It is actually called Firmware, or rather a section of the firmware that is exposed via ACPI interface. uEFI is just another part of the firmware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is stored in an ACPI table named `MSDM` which can be retrieved via

```
~# xxd /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM 
00000000: 4d53 444d 5500 0000 0364 4d45 4449 4f4e  MSDMU....dMEDION
00000010: 4d45 4449 4f4e 4147 0000 0000 5445 5354  MEDIONAG....TEST
00000020: 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 1d00 0000 1234 1234 1234 1234  ........HERE-THE
00000040: 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234  WINDOWS-PRODUCT-
00000050: 1234 1234 12                             KEY
```

Or, even simpler

```
~# strings /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM 
MSDMU
dMEDIONMEDIONAG
TEST
YOUR-WINDOWS-LICENCE
```

[Source](https://hangg.com/2015/11/windows-key-unter-linux-aus-bios-auslesen/)

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.